# Testing a directive that changes the HTML node element during $compile time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-runner

EDIT: it seems that the compile of the directive happens after the test has already failed.

Test:
I have provided a full mock of the service function that I need for my directive.
When running the test in debug mode(by adding a break point) the everything seems correct.
Tried so far:
Diminishing the priority of the directive, suing $digest instead compile, and many others.

```
  describe('restrict', function(){
    var scope, compile, html, elem, authService;
    html = '<span data-restrict data-access="admin"></span>';
    beforeEach(function(){
      module('myApp.directives');
      module('myApp.services');
      inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $injector){
        authService = $injector.get('authService');
        authService.setRole('guest');
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        compile = $compile;
      });
    });
  it('should allow basic role-based content discretion', function(){
        expect(elem.length).toEqual(0); 
        console.log(elem);//HTML node
        timeout(function(){
          console.log(elem);//undefined
        }, 500);
   });
});
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
directive('restrict', function(authService){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        prioriry: 100000,
        scope: false,
        compile: function(element, attr, linker){
      debugger;//The test has already failed one I reach this break point!
            var accessDenied = true;
            var user = authService.getUser();
            var attributes = attr.access.split(" ");
            for(var i in attributes){
                if(user.role == attributes[i]){
                    accessDenied = false;
                }
            }

            if(accessDenied){

          angular.forEach(element.children(), function(elm){
            try{
              elm.remove();
            }
            catch(ignore){}
          });//TODO: find a better solution for IE or remove this code       

        element.children().remove();
                element.remove();           
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Test output:

```
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Linux) restrict should allow basic role-based content discretion FAILED
    Expected { 0 : HTMLNode, length : 1 } to equal 0.
    Error: Expected { 0 : HTMLNode, length : 1 } to equal 0.
        at null.<anonymous> (/var/www/front/dev/angular-seed/test/unit/directivesSpec.js:19:22)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

You need to make the assertion outside of the AngularJS $digest cycle, by setting a timeout of 0:

```
    it('should allow basic role-based content discretion', function(){
        timeout(function(){
          expect(elem).toBeUndefined(); 
        }, 0);
    });
  });
```

Test output:

```
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Linux): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.537 secs / 0.061 secs)
```